# Flask/Jinja2 error Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm starting to use Flask and I find myself standing on this next mistake:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'.
```

I don't know exactly where the error is, I've already redo the code but I still have the same problem! Here's the code:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/page1")
def page1():
    return render_template("page1.html")

@app.route("/page2")
def more():
    return render_template("page2.html")
```

**layout.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My website </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> {$ block heading %}{% endblock heading %}} </h1>

        {% block body %}
        {% endblock body %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block heading %}
    First Page
{% endblock heading %}

{% block body %}
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>

    <a href="{{ url_for('more') }}"> Leia Mais. </a>
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
{% endblock %}
```

In place of the specific endblock things you're using.

Oh, I also see you're doing this:

```
{$ block heading %}{% endblock heading %}}
```

There are three problems here:

1. you have a `$` symbol, and
2. you have two end `}`
3. as mentioned before, the endblock should just be this: `{% endblock %}`

Comment: Same error, I had tried this way before I specified them, I tried this way cause I saw someone else here at stackoverflow doing this way 

If that helps, that's what it shows when I try to open the site: https://prnt.sc/rrteru

Comment: @PedroBzz: I saw some other problems in your code. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! I ended up letting this mistake go, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

sometimes errors may arise because of not giving correct spacing in {%%}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31376769)