# Can anyone explain this error in the image below

Tags: python, html, flask, error-handling, syntax-error

[[enter image description here[enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YulKy.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nTtB.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I92O5.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J58gG.jpg)
I ran the program but it shows error 500 and GET error and syntax endblock error. I am using flask.

I tried for making a simple program in the webpage

Comment: Please post your code and error as text. Images of code can not be accepted on stack overflow.

Comment: ... and also choose a specific title (you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using stack overflow for a question. Will correct it next time

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in entry.html between { and %. it should be **{% block body %}**. try it.

[A similar question for your reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999735/flask-jinja2-error-encountered-unknown-tag-endblock)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your Jinja template code more neat way. I can see your `{% block %}` code has redundant spaces. You can fix this as below for instance.

```html
{% block body %}

<-- Contents -->

{% endblock %}
```